# Does standardization require the existence of normally distributed features?

Tags: machine-learning, normality-assumption, standardization, data-preprocessing

In some resources, websites, and blogs, I saw an assertion related to standardization operation in machine learning, and I could not make sure whether it is really true or not. The assertion is given below.

> The features have to be normally distributed so that standardization operation performed on that data set can provide benefit for it. In other words, if the features are not from Gaussian distribution, scaling them by standardization is meaningless.

Is this really true? I am asking, because many people around me do not check whether the features are really distributed in a Gaussian form, and directly apply standardization process.

Comment: The claim that it is "meaningless" is absurd. Standardisation to mean 0 and SD 1 has a meaning as what it does. It can be helpful if the main deal is getting variables on comparable scale. What standardisation does not do is make variables closer to normal: as a linear rescaling it can't make them closer or indeed further away from normal. Normality can make some things clearer or simpler, but it is not an absolute goal.

Comment: *Extremely* few procedures in statistics or data mining require that features exhibit Normal distributions.  Of more primary concern are how *symmetric* those distributions might be and how frequently they exhibit extraordinary values ("outliers").

Comment: More silly dogma. Where did you find this? Here is another meaning for standardized scores, absent normality:  At least 88.9% of the standardized scores are between -3 and +3. Chebychev's inequality applies to all distributions with finite variance, and it always applies to empirical distributions (with the mild caveat that you use "$n$"  instead of "$n-1$" in the variance formula), so it applies to all data sets.